# Symfony - .gitignore and vendor dir

Tags: git, symfony

in my *.gitignore* file I have added '/vendor/'.
Unfortunately when I run command **git status**, console shows me a lot of vendors files and dirs.
How I can avoit it?

Comment: Having `/vendor/` in your .gitignore shouldn't be problem. Run `git rm -rf --cached vendor` first then run `git status` again to see if it goes away. I just suspect that you might have staged or committed it before by accident.

Comment: [How to make Git “forget” about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: Did you commit your `.gitignore` file yet?  If you haven't, `git status` will still show those files.

Answer (score 3):

Having `/vendor/` in your *.gitignore* shouldn't be problem. Run `git rm -rf --cached vendor` first then run `git status` again to see if it goes away. I just suspect that you might have staged or committed it before by accident.

Answer (score -1):

I assume vendor directory is in your git cloned repository, if so you need to rename the entry in .gitignore file as follow.

`/vendors` or just `vendors` works fine

Comment: Well no.  /vendor/ will work just fine.  git works off of the repository location and knows nothing about the rest of your system.

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong. Downvoted accordingly.

Answer (score -3):

Use the relative path instead of absolute i.e. add `vendor/` to `.gitignore` file instead of `/vendor/`

Comment: Well no.  /vendor/ is perfectly fine.

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong.  Downvoted accordingly.